# Multiple columns with ContainsTable and boolean logic with full text index

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have what I think is a very basic scenario, but what I've read makes it sound like this is not easy using SQL Server Full Text catalog and indexes.

I have 2 columns, First and Last name.  I want to support full-text search on them such that if someone types "John Smith" people with a match on **both** first and last come up first.

Although it's easy to create an index across multiple columns, and easy to search multiple columns, the scoring doesn't reflect multiple columns.

```
SELECT [Key], Rank 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE([User], (FirstName,LastName), '<CLAUSE_HERE>')
```

1. If CLAUSE_HERE is "john smith" I get no results, because that phrase does not exist in either field.
2. If it's "john OR smith" I get all users with either name in either field, sorted in an unhelpful order.
3. If it's "john AND smith" I get no results, because neither field contains both words.

Seems like the only solution is to autogenerate a query that runs `containstable` on each field, does some math, sums the scores, etc.  Does that sound right?  Is there an easier way around it?  My actual query has a lot more fields to it - this is a simplified example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) which mushes together the fields that you're interested in searching on (in a way that makes sense for your search formats), and full-text index that.

As far as I'm aware this is the only work around if you want to full-text in this way because of the behavior you describe in your question.

Comment: Totally worked!!  Why doesn't full text do this automatically?  I thought that applying full text on multiple columns would work like this out-of-the-box.  guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to test it, but I wonder if you might be able to use the ISABOUT() function to apply a weight to each keyword.  Your search clause might look something like:

```
ISABOUT(john weight(0.2), smith weight(0.8))
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it doesn't work.  The way the scoring works doesn't appear to sum across columns.  So, "John Smith" gets the exact same score as "John Jones" in my tests.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Do you have a sample / test script?