# How can i use full text index to find records which begin with a specific character or word?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, wildcard

I have the following query with `LIKE` condition:

`Select top 20 * from entity with(NOLOCK) where first like 'john%'`

The Above query will return the employee whose first name starts with John.
Now the same query using Full-Text Index search:

```
Select top 20 * from entity with(NOLOCK) WHERE Contains(First,'John').
```

The above code returns all the records which contains phase john in first name.

How to make the second query return the exact matching records, that is those beginning with *John*.

The desired result is shown on this picture below:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM entity WHERE Contains(First,'John')
) 
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM cte WHERE cte.First like 'John%'
```

this way Full-Text search will select ALL records containing John and the outer `SELECT ... LIKE` will choose only those starting with `John`.

**UPDATE:** you can also order inner Full-Text search results by matching Rank and then join to your `entity` table like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [KEY],[Rank] from CONTAINSTABLE(entity, First, 'John', 9999)
) 
SELECT TOP 20 e.* from cte
    INNER JOIN entity e on cte.[Key]=e.PK_Entity
WHERE e.First like 'John%'
```

replace e.PK_Entity with the entity table Primary Key.

Note, the above query will first select top 9999 records containing string `John` ordered by matching Rank and the second `SELECT` will `JOIN` to the `entity` table to get those records starting with John.

To make it work faster and depending on the number of records in your table you can lower the 9999 number in the `CONTAINSTABLE` call if you don't need so many results from Full-Text Search. Just don't make it 20, because top 20 matching rows does not necessarily begin with *John* .

HTH

Comment: Thank You andrews ! Will this be effective for bigger database(Big Data).

Comment: @Avi ummm you may need to tune the initial FTS search result. Granted that you cannot display all 9999 records in a single page view you can change this value to 1000 for example and observe execution time.

Comment: @Avi, does you table have a proper non-clustered index on `First` column? If yes, is your your original query with LIKE taking too much time to complete?

Comment: Yeah you are right , I am not going to show 10000 records at stretch,But i am using typeahead js to search and display the records of 50.

Comment: @Avi what is the size of the `entity` table? Do you have the index I mentioned earlier? You should definitely try 1. LIKE only query with index 2. Changing FTS TOP records threshold from 9999 to say 200-300. Please, accept my edit to your question which is still pending.

Comment: I am using the Index. I need one more help andrews. I am using first and last name to search the records in table.Now i need to search the records based on state and county. Check this https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/. In the above url if you type texas john,it will return the data containing the name john in state texas

Comment: @avi the best would be to create a computed column gluing together First and Last names and then defining fulltext index over this computed column as opposite to trying to check First and Last cols separately. See for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801285/multiple-columns-with-containstable-and-boolean-logic-with-full-text-index .

Comment: @Avi if my answer has solved your problem would you pls mark it as the accepted one? Juts hit grey the checkmark to the left of the answer under the down arrow.