# SQL Server CONTAINS doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I have an address table, and I want to search over that with the free text function CONTAINS.

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[ID_AddressType]
      ,[Name1]
      ,[Name2]
      ,[Street]
      ,[Number]
      ,[ZipCode]
      ,[City]
      ,[Country]
  FROM [TrailerLoadingAssistant].[dbo].[Address]
  WHERE CONTAINS((Name1, Name2, Street, Number, ZipCode, City, Country), '"Bier*" AND "742*"')
```

In my table, there is an entry, where the street name starts with Bier and the zip code with 742. Why doesn't the script find the entry? If I replace the AND with an OR, it works, but it also finds other entries, where only one of the search terms is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a calculated column to my `Address` table, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1801296/10406502). That contains all relevant fields. The full text index now only consideres this virtual column.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[ID_AddressType]
      ,[Name1]
      ,[Name2]        
      ,[Street]
      ,[Number]
      ,[ZipCode]
      ,[City]
      ,[Country]
  FROM [TrailerLoadingAssistant].[dbo].[Address]
  WHERE CONTAINS((Name1, Name2, Street, Number, ZipCode, City, Country), 'Bier*')
  AND CONTAINS((Name1, Name2, Street, Number, ZipCode, City, Country), '742*')
```

**Note:-** You can try this, by separating both the value....and i'm don't know column table value containing `'Bier*' or only 'Bier'`

Comment: Microsoft states in their Documentation, that you should not add multiple CONTAINS statements due to performance reasons, and you should the inline AND function instead.